# DATEPART queries with SQLAlchemy give DBAPIError

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, sybase, pyodbc

I am trying to make a query which matches month and year provided as a parameter to select records from DB.

Here's the code

```
from sqlalchemy import func, and_

query = session.query(Table).filter(and_(func.extract("month", Table.c.added_date) == month,
                                         func.extract("year", Table.c.added_date) == year))
```

Running the same gives this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: '' is not a recognized datepart option.\n
```

I am not able to get a handle on the problem even after doing lots of googling. Any help is appreciated.

PS - Database is Sybase ASE

Comment: Perhaps try `func.extract(text("month"), Table.c.added_date)`

Comment: @GordThompson I tried your suggestion. It gave me the same error

Comment: Does `func.datepart(text("month"), Table.c.added_date)` work any better?

Comment: You query should work. Can you actually print the generated query using `print(query.statement.compile(session.get_bind().dialect, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))`?

Comment: @GordThompson `func.datepart(text("month"), Table.c.added_date)` worked. Thanks very much